# ListView repeating some ImageViews in all the rows

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, baseadapter

I found a lot of questions around this topic, but none could help me. So here it goes.

I'm building a ListView using a this BaseAdapter

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
int layout;
Person[] mpeople;

public PostListAdapter(Context context,int layout, Person[] people){
    this.context=context;
    this.layout=layout;
    this.mpeople=people;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v=convertView;

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
    }

    Person swig=mpeople[position];

    ImageView profilepic= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.profilepic);
    profilepic.setImageResource(swig.getUser().getProfilepic());
    TextView username= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    username.setText(swig.getUser().getUsername());
    TextView timestamp= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
    timestamp.setText(Integer.toString(swig.getTimestamp()));
    TextView privacy= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.privacy);
    privacy.setText(swig.getPrivacy());
    TextView hashtag= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.hashtagtext);
    hashtag.setText(swig.getHashtag());
    TextView n_likes= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.likenumber);
    n_likes.setText(Integer.toString(swig.getN_likes()));
    TextView n_comments= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.commentnumber);
    n_comments.setText(Integer.toString(swig.getN_comments()));

    ImageView cell1= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cell1);
    cell1.setImageResource(swig.getPics()[0]);
    ImageView cell2= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cell2);
    cell2.setImageResource(swig.getPics()[1]);
    ImageView cell3= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cell3);
    cell3.setImageResource(swig.getPics()[2]);
    ImageView cell4= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cell4);
    cell4.setImageResource(swig.getPics()[3]);
    ImageView cell5= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cell5);
    cell5.setImageResource(swig.getPics()[4]);
    ImageView cell6= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cell6);
    cell6.setImageResource(swig.getPics()[5]);
    ImageView cell7= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cell7);
    cell7.setImageResource(swig.getPics()[6]);
    ImageView cell8= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cell8);
    cell8.setImageResource(swig.getPics()[7]);
    ImageView cell9= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cell9);
    cell9.setImageResource(swig.getPics()[8]);

    return v; 
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mpeople.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return mpeople[arg0];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return arg0;
}

}
```

The Array People[] is created on a fragment and every entry is different [it is, I checked], but for some reason when I run the code some elements of the code aren't.

All the ImageViews cell1 to cell9 only show the images of the last entry.

If any more code or info is needed feel free to ask.

Thanks in advance.

---

SOLVED

The problem was in the creation of the array,something really minor and nothing to do with the adapter.

Comment: ... and after you make it work following other people's advices, take a look also at the ViewHolder pattern to get rid of all those findViewById, it's a really slow call and your next question will be: "why my list scrolls so slow?"

Comment: Thank you for the advice, already did the changes needed and I'm using ViewHolder.

Comment: Turns how my checking skills are not that good and after checking again the problem was in the array itself. So, the Adapter was doing its job.

Comment: cool! even though it was doing its job, with the ViewHolder pattern you are saving a lot of time. On smaller adapters maybe it's not much of a difference, but in your case you have tons of findViewById's: The ListView would have been constantly executing them everytime a view entered or exited the view space (hundreds of times in the case of a fast scroll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seem could work like:

```
  if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
 }
 /*
 ** you intitalize your findeviewbyid after when your view not getting null So its 
   recreate your inflatore view  this is not corect way
 *
  */

ImageView profilepic= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.profilepic);
```

***e.g     from your code
         Your code should be intialize view id into convertview==null   condtion is met***

```
  Person swig=mpeople[position];
  if (convertView == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
    ImageView profilepic= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.profilepic);
    ImageView cell2= (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.cell2);
}
 cell1.setImageResource(swig.getPics());
 cell2.setImageResource(swig.getPics()[1]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
If I put all the findViewById inside the if statment and all the setImageResource outside, the list shows only three entries from the list repeated, and the cell1 to cell9 are still the same on every row.

Comment: Turns how my checking skills are not that good and after checking again the problem was in the array itself. So, the Adapter was doing its job.

Comment: there's also an error here, cell2 is outside its declared scope. And If you move the declaration near Person and assign it on convertView, it will hold the value of the ImageView of when the convertView was created (hence the repetition). Again, this error disappears when you use the ViewHolder :)